# onLocationUpdate is never called in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gps

I am trying to get user's location but it seems like onLocationUpdate is never triggered, I tried to run this app on multiple devices same result.

I tried to Google before posting here,  couldn't find any solution. And, Android Internet,GPS COARSE and GPS FINE permissions added in manifest file.

Here's my whole activity code

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // Checking if we got permission
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_restaurants);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(NearbyRestaurants.this, location.getLatitude()+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.i("Location Update!", location.toString())
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }else{
            Log.i("Checking Location","Checking Location Wait");

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you also try to add NETWORK_PROVIDER when requesting location

requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);